# Anomaly and Weyl spinors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, wick-rotation, quantum-anomalies

I try to better understand anomalies in QFT and I've got a question concerning derivation of axial anomaly in [Terning's lectures (page 12)](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306119)

Consider a theory of Weyl fermions coupled to a gauge field $A_{\mu}^{a}$
$$
S_{\text{ferm}} = \int \, d^4x \, \imath \bar{\psi} \bar{\sigma}_{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}+\imath A_{\mu}^a \, T^a) \psi
$$
On a classical level transformation
$$
\psi \rightarrow e^{\imath \alpha} \psi
$$
is a symmetry of a theory and conserving current is
$$
j_{\mu} = \bar{\psi}\bar{\sigma}_{\mu} \psi
$$
On a quantum level it is not true and we have anomaly. Terning derives expression for divergence of an axial current using Fujikawa's path integral method. He introduces two operators
$$
\hat{D} = \imath \, \bar{\sigma}^{\mu}_E (\partial_{\mu}+\imath A_{\mu})
$$
$$
\hat{\bar{D}} = \imath \, \sigma^{\mu}_E (\partial_{\mu}-\imath A_{\mu})
$$
and shows that $\hat{D}^{\dagger}=\hat{\bar{D}}$. So, the question is why do we have to do a Wick rotation and use Euclidian Pauli matrices? Naively, I should say that this expression
$$
\int dx \, \bar{\psi} \hat{D} \xi = \int \, \bar{\xi} \hat{\bar{D}} \psi
$$
is also correct in Minkowskian spacetime.

Comment: It's not about this particular expression, it's that later in the derivation you want to use some Gaussian exponentials which would have an $\mathrm{i}$ in them in Minkowski space, and that wouldn't converge nicely to the desired result.